# Get the amount of steps taken without a trigger / onSensorChanged

Tags: android, sensors

Using Androids sensor libs it is possible to extract the steps taken in a trigger function called "onSensorChanged".

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  String steps = String.valueOf(event.values[0]);
  ...
}
```

The array "event.values[0]" will hold the current steps taken since last phone reboot as the Android Dev Docs says. Beginning to walk will call "onSensorChanged", and the steps can be collected.

Is there a way to collect the last known step count without calling "onSensorChanged" or even walking from inside any onCreate method or alike?

Example imaginary code:

```
SensorEventValues sev = new SensorEventValues();
Toast.(This,sev.values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```